# 3-way switch issue

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch

I'm having an issue with a 3-way switch that I have not gotten around to fixing in many years. When I use switch A to turn on the light and then use switch B to try to turn it off, it flickers off and then back on. When I use switch B to turn on the light and then use switch A to try to turn it off, nothing happens. Any advice on what is causing this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace switch B. Sounds like something broke inside the switch.

Comment: And take very special care to identify the **travelers** before removing any wires.   Travelers are on the brass screws and always go into the same cable.  I mark them with yellow tape. **Trying to identify travelers *after* you have removed the old switch is a nightmare**.  You can't go by screw position, every switch is different.

Answer (score 1):

Start out by checking the connections on switch B, especially the travelers which hopefully will be marked in yellow. If all is good, replace the switch. Since you've been having the problem for years, replace both switches, they are pretty inexpensive.
Take a picture of the back of the switches before unhooking any wires. There is no standard for the connections and the new switches might not be the same as the old ones. Good luck

Comment: There's no Code requirement or even a best practice to mark travelers yellow, unfortunately.  That may be local to SE.   It is extremely useful to novices, because identifying travelers "the hard way" is so darned hard.  And we deal with novices a lot obviously.

Comment: @Harper Just trying to teach him a little about Harper's law.